# Как отключить звук в конкретном application на iOS?

Tags: ios

Вопрос к гуру iOS'а.

Есть ли какой-то способ (можно хаком) программно выключить звук в других запущенных апликейшенах, кроме своего (например, вырубить звук в Spotify player)?

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял:

Например, можно воспроизвести какой-нибудь звук (музыку) через AVPlayer или AVAudioPlayer в Вашем приложении и это перебьет воспроизведение звука (музыки) из другого приложения (остановит воспроизведение).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html